# Centering The Page

Tags: html, css, layout, centering, absolute

I am having trouble trying to center everything on the page. I know I have positioned certain items on the page down from top and in from left, is there any possible way to still center with these settings on. If i take top and left options off the menu boxes seem to alight themselves down the center of the page vertically but I need them to stay horizontal.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="social1">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Scottish-Game-Jam/136412446403315"><img         src="images/faccebook.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="image" ></a>
</div>

<div class="social2">
<a href="https://twitter.com/ScottishGameJam"><img src="images/Twitter.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="image"> </a></div>



<div class="logo">
<img  src="Untitled-2.png" alt="Logo" width="120"px" length="120px" ></div>


<div class="container2">

<div id="demo">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="GameJamHomepage.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="Registration.html"><span>Register</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="Gallery.html"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="Location.html"><span>Location</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>




<div id="demo2">
<nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="News.html"><span>News</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="Supporters.html"><span>Support</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="FAQ.html"><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="ContactUs.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>

</div>



</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.social1 { position:absolute;
top:5px;
left: 30px;}

.social1 a:hover {display:block;  width:32; length:32; color: #F0C;} 

.social2 { position:absolute;
top:5px;
left: 70px;}

.social2 a:hover {display:block;  width:32; length:32; color: #F0C;} 


.logo {position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:30px;}

body{
background-color: #000;
text-align: center;}

#container {position:absolute; margin:auto;
text-align:left;
width:450px;}



#container2 { position:absolute;}




#demo nav ul li a {display: block; width: 120px; height: 120px;
background-image: url(icons.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;}

#demo nav ul li:nth-child(1) a {
background-color: #5bb2fc;
position:absolute;
top:190px;
left:30px;}

#demo nav ul li:nth-child(2) a {
background-color: #58ebd3;
position:absolute;
top:190px; left:160px;}

#demo nav ul li:nth-child(3) a {
background-color: #ffa659;
position:absolute;
top:190px;
left: 290px;    }

#demo nav ul li:nth-child(4) a {
background-color: #ff7a85;
position:absolute;
top:190px;
left: 420px;    }

#demo2 nav ul li a {display: block; width: 120px; height: 120px;
        background-image: url(icons.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; }

#demo2 nav ul li:nth-child(1) a {background-color: #5bb2fc;
            position:absolute;top:320px;left:30px;}

#demo2 nav ul li:nth-child(2) a {
            background-color: #58ebd3;
            position:absolute;
top:320px;
left:160px;
        }
#demo2 nav ul li:nth-child(3) a {
            background-color: #ffa659;
            position:absolute;top:320px;left:290px;         }

#demo2 nav ul li:nth-child(4) a {background-color: #ff7a85;
            position:absolute;top:320px;left:420px; }


nav ul li a span {font: 50px "Dosis", sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;position: fixed;                 left:600px; top: 190px;    display: none;  }

#demo nav ul li a:hover { display:block; height:120px;
width:120px;
background-color:#3333CC;}



#demo2 nav ul li a:hover { display:block; height:120px;
width:120px;background-color:#3333CC }

nav ul li a:hover span {display: block;}

nav ul li:nth-child(1) a span { color: #5bb2fc;                 }

nav ul li:nth-child(2) a span { color: #58ebd3;         }

nav ul li:nth-child(3) a span {color: #ffa659;}

nav ul li:nth-child(4) a span {
                color: #ff7a85;}
```

Comment: Side note, there is no length attribute. `length="120px"` or `length:32;`

Comment: Typo; `width="120"px"`

Comment: You're massively overusing positioning though....there are much better (and more flexible) layout methods. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this a little more, I am not a very advanced web designer at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the elements easily, the only thing that you have to do is set `margin: auto;`

If you also want that the `li` elements in the `ul` to stay in the same line you must set `float: left;` in the css file.